# using "return" in function or define global variable by "<<-" which of them? in R

Tags: r

Is it appropriate to use global variable in the function instead of `return`? If not, why?

```
mysum <- function(a, b) {
    c <<- a + b
}
```

or

```
mysum <- function(a, b){
    c <- a + b
    return(c)
}
```

Comment: That's a general programming concept, called [side effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)). For discussion, check [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/40297/what-is-a-side-effect) and [this](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/15269/why-are-side-effects-considered-evil-in-functional-programming).

Comment: Maybe this question is duplicated, a short answer might be: it depends on what you want to achieve. Anyway do not use `<<-` because of reasons explained in "Circle 6" of "The R Inferno" by Patrick Burns. you can find it here: http://www.burns-stat.com/documents/books/the-r-inferno/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a global variable like you do in your first alternative is referred to in programming circles as a "side effect" (see the comments for some links to discussions). It is frowned upon, one compelling reasons is that it makes it hard to understand pieces of your program in isolation and hard to reuse that code in other places.

The second method is of course preferred, that is the whole point of the "return" statement. One of the main reasons people tend to the first choice is that in the other it appears difficult to return multiple values. However this can be achieved in various ways, perhaps the simplest is using a list like so:

```
mysumdiff <- function(a,b){

  rv <- list(sum=a+b,diff=a-b)
  return(rv)
}

msd <- mysumdiff(3,4)

print(sprintf("sum: %d diff:%d",msd$sum,msd$diff))
```